# completely disable mouse in console vim

Tags: vim, mouse, mintty

I'm using Vim under babun (cygwin).
What really annoys me are the problems with mouse.
I want to completly disable it. I tried to add to my vimrc everything that I found on net, but nothing works.

Take a look at this little presentation. There you can see all my defined settings and what is still wrong. I have no problem with the left mouse button. This one does nothing. Problem is with right button and even more problem is with the scroll. The scroll adds additional characters what you can see at this gif. Right button add new empty line or pastes something. How to get rid of this all?

[image]

Comment: Just a note if you want to disable it in every mode, you better use `map` than a combination of imap,vmap,nmap...

Comment: You say you tried "everything you found" on the net? I assume that includes clearing the "mouse" option? Is your gif captured while the "mouse" option is empty?

Comment: @Ben it looks like it. Notice how its copying the line numbers.

Comment: @Ben isn't clearning the mouse option set in 7th line from top? This gif was captured with all the options and mappings as you can see on it

Comment: Gotcha, I wasn't paying attention to the file in the screenshot, only the behavior. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing this is not a vim issue, but a cygwin issue.  When you right click it is pasting, to vim it is just like you are typing whatever is in your clipboard.

1) Right click in cygwin, choose options (aka preferences or settings)

2) Select mouse in the left menu, and select something other than paste

For the scrollwheel issue... well mousewheel events are encoded as follows:

> line up     ^[Oa
>
> line down   ^[Ob
>
> page up     ^[[1;2a
>
> page down   ^[[1;2b

So you would need to map those to do nothing:

```
map <Esc>Oa <Nop> 
map <Esc>Ob <Nop> 
map <Esc>[1;2a <Nop> 
map <Esc>[1;2b <Nop> 
map! <Esc>Oa <Nop> 
map! <Esc>Ob <Nop> 
map! <Esc>[1;2a <Nop> 
map! <Esc>[1;2b <Nop>
```